# how can I fix UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 12 to dimension: type=0x3

Tags: android, android-library, android-buildconfig

so We recently updated our buildToolsVersion to 26.0.2   And now our code crashes in the CircularProgressButton library that we are using when trying to create a CircularProgressButton ([see library](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button) I know we get what we deserve using a non supported library).

The stack trace says that it is caused by an InflationException "Binary XML file line #0".  But when I track it down while debugging I can see that the TypedArray.getDimension() call is throwing an UnsupportedOperationExcetion which is the true root cause of the crash.  What's happening in the getDimension() method is that we are expecting the TypedValue to be a TYPE_DIMENSION    but it is a TYPE_STRING.  Does any one know where I can look to see how/were  the attributes or TypedValue is being set?

Full Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal/com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.nav.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: 
Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.auth.OnboardingFragment.onCreateView(OnboardingFragment.java:111)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1340)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2155)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2064)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2270)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1381)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1569)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2984)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:203)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:613)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at com.trello.rxlifecycle2.components.support.RxAppCompatActivity.onStart(RxAppCompatActivity.java:66)
        at com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:75)
        at com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.nav.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:328)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6268)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.dd.CircularProgressButton
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parse
```

EDIT:  here is an place in XML were we are using the CircularProgressButton.  It has not been changed in some time.

```
 <com.dd.CircularProgressButton
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:cpb_colorIndicator="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:cpb_colorIndicatorBackground="@color/cpb_grey"
            app:cpb_colorProgress="?android:colorBackground"
            app:cpb_selectorIdle="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:cpb_textIdle="@string/login_btn" />
```

Comment: The layout for your MainActivity presumably includes some CircularProgressButton tags. What are you setting for the attribute `app:cpb_cornerRadius`?

Comment: We are not setting the cornerRadius we never have. I've added the relevant xml to my question if it helps.

Comment: If you delete the `style` attribute as well as the various `app:cpb_` attributes, can you successfully inflate the XML or do you get the same error?

Comment: If I delete the `style` attribut it still crashes if I delete `style` and `app:cpb_` attributes It inflates the xml successfully.

Comment: Sounds like the `<declare-styleable>` element in the library project is somehow being compiled incorrectly. There are only two dimensions used for that view: `cpb_cornerRadius` and `cpb_paddingProgress`, but it seems like your `app:cpb_textIdle="@string/login_btn"` is somehow being passed to `getDimension()`

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No, I had to use a different library.

Comment: @Burf2000 I ended using this library by the same person which is still supported.  https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-morphing-button

Comment: Was the upgrade path fairly simple? We brought the source code in to the app but would prefer a gradle fix

Comment: Ya it was reasonably simple.  We just call morphToProgress() and the log in button animates into a progress indicator (still a button so set clickable to false).   If you save the layout params before morphing the button then if the log in fails you can just call morph() passing in a MorphingButton.Params  object and it changes back to the way it looked before.

Answer (score 0):

In the project's build.gradle, configure the gradle version to 2.3.3, it works for me.

```
buildscript {
    // other codes

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```